# Creating a hidden product

Tags: php, curl, shopify

I am trying to `POST` the contents of [request.json](http://pastebin.com/WKj8xgtf) to 
`/admin/products.json`, but Shopify replies with the contents of 
[response.json](http://pastebin.com/3VHBnkJA).

As you can see in [request.json](http://pastebin.com/WKj8xgtf), I have specified "`published_at`" to be 
null in attempt to make the product "hidden", but then Shopify is overriding that value 
with a generated timestamp as in [response.json](http://pastebin.com/3VHBnkJA). If I hide a product via 
the Shopify Admin panel, then GET /admin/products.json, the 
"`published_at`" correctly has a value of `null`.

Either the [documentation](http://wiki.shopify.com/Using_the_shopify_api_gem_with_the_credentials_of_a_private_app#Hide_.E2.80.94_or_publish_.E2.80.94_a_bunch_of_products) is incorrect, or there is a bug with the Shopify API (ignoring the "`null`" value on "`published_at`" in `POST` requests).

Comment: I vote for the _"there is a bug with the Shopify API"_... What does `"published": false` do for you?

Comment: Same result, I've tried `false`, `null`, `0`, as well as all of them as a string.

Comment: Just to make sure: That's with `"published": false`, NOT `"published_at": false`?

Comment: I've been using `"published_at": false` as that is what is specified in the docs, and that is also the parameter used by Shopify itself. If I create a product using the Shopify Admin UI, `"published_at"` is set to a timestamp of when I created it. If I then hide the product, `"published_at"` is set to `null` in the JSON response of `/admin/products.json`. So it seems pretty clear that `published_at` is the correct key to use, the Shopify API just seems to ignore it. I'll give `published` a go now.

Comment: Well. there's a clear example with that `published:false` [in these examples at least](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create), and as they are about the json api rather then the ruby one...

Comment: Ok that worked, really bizarre that it says to use `publish_at` for Ruby when, regardless of language, you will get the exact same result when you encode the object as JSON to send to the API. It sounds like the Ruby documentation must just be out of date. Also really bizarre API design that Shopify use `published` for writing and `published_at` for reading. Add it as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[according to these examples](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create), the correct way to prevent publishing of *new* products, is to set:

```
  published: false
```

As to why the ruby gem example differs from the json one: well, the json one is about a new product, the ruby one is about updating existing products, that might be a difference, but I'd call it an inconsistency in the API, most likely due to the fact they consider a `null` `published_at` for new products the same as `unset`, and default to `now`.

Comment: Thank you, have been looking for this all over, worked for me